# Using timestamp field to auto complete source field in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to use my timestamp field to autocomplete my source field in QGIS using the field calculator. I want my source field to be completed with a saved string e.g "Sam_Sam". I want my source field updated with name each time i create or edit a feature.I have this

```
CASE WHEN "timestamp"  =  $now  THEN 'Sam_Sam' END.
```

It's not working

Can anyone can help with something better?

Comment: The `$now` function returns the date and time (to the second). I haven't tested this but I would guess that this would only work if you run it at an **exact** time which matches the same time value in your "timestamp" field. Could you perhaps [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/167576/edit) your question to include a description of what you are trying to achieve please? This could help potential answerers :)

Comment: Thank you Joseph for your reply. The exact result i wanted is that whenever i edit, update or create a feature... the timestamp changes, so i want my source field to be automatically updated with the provided string e.g 'Sam_Sam'. So eahc time my timestamp field changes, i want tha source field to automatically be updated. I think writing a function will do the job easily but i am not proficient in python.

Comment: How are you generating the timestamp field at the moment?